# Is it possible to display {{BASEPAGENAME}} with non-filing characters?

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to remove parts of a title displayed with {{BASEPAGENAME}} or other magic words?

For example, say I have a page titled:

`(2015.04.08) Test`

Is it possible to display the title without the first 13 characters so it just displays 'Test' instead?

I can't seem to finagle #titleparts to work, since the bracketed date information isn't actually what's considered a *part* of the title. What I have in mind is more like nonfiling characters in MARC code (http://www.library.yale.edu/cataloging/music/filing.htm) - modifying the number of characters to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a look at the Lua module [Module:String](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Module:String), that will allow you to fetch the title without the first 13 characters like this:

```
{{#invoke:String|sub|{{BASEPAGENAME}}|13|-1}}
```

You can also do much more complex parsing, based on patterns. The String module will only work if you have enabled Lua on your wiki with the [Scribunto extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto), and you will need to copy the [module source](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Module:String&action=edit) to your wiki.

If, for some reason, you can not use Lua, a much more inefficient way is to enable the [Extension:ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions). This comes bundled with recent versions of MediaWiki, so you just need to enable it in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/ParserFunctions/ParserFunctions.php";
$wgPFEnableStringFunctions = true;
```

`$wgPFEnableStringFunctions` will give you access to a number of [string parsing functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StringFunctions), allowing you to do something like:

```
{{#sub:{{BASEPAGENAME}}|13|0}}
```

Comment: Thank you. Informative and helpful both - you explained enough that it makes sense to a rookie like me.

Comment: Good regex advice, but `$wgRestrictDisplayTitle = false;` is needed to actually use that as title (or ugly workarounds in JavaScript).